# Update terminal emacs -nw to 22.3 on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm using emacs on OSX Terminal, and it is on 22.1 version, I just downloaded the 22.3 and installed it (.dmg), but it only works with an GUI interface, if I do a "emacs -nw" command, it still opens the old version (22.1). How can I make this termial command open the newer version with no window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just solved it, under /Applications/.../ there was an bin file called Emacs, just move it/link to the /usr/bin/ and it works with the newer version.

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the answer to mark this question solved.